# How to repair burn marks on leather clothes?

Tags: clothing, repair

I left a leather jacket hanging on a chair by the dinner table, there was something hot nearby and now it has a burn mark on the shoulder. It's like the leather shrunk where the heat was, and the surrounding is all wrinkled.

[image]

Other than cutting the shrunk part and patching the hole, or replacing the whole shoulder piece with similar leather, is there any other method to repair this kind of damage?

Comment: Is this genuine leather? I would have expected this kind of damage with faux leather?

Comment: @Stephie Yes, it is.

Answer (score 1):

First, you might try gentle spraying with water with a *tiny* amount of detergent added, and letting the jacket sit in a closed container for a few days, to see if the damage is reduced. Don't leave it wet for too long lest it mildew.

There are also commercial [leather repair kits](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B018EBKBXC) and [patch kits](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0042K83DU) that can be used to make repairs. (*Caveat*: I've not tried them myself.)

An alternative would be to add a decorative patch, such as for a team, national park or product, over the damage.